# Bresenham's algorithm next pixel?

Tags: algorithm, bresenham, line-drawing

In line drawing, bresenham's algorithm was explicitly derived for lines with slopes between 0 and 1 in the first octant from point P1 to point P2, where the x value of P1 is less than that for P2.

In the incremental version of this algorithm, once a pixel is drawn, we need to choose the next pixel to draw.

What are the choices? How do we go about choosing which pixel to draw next? (assuming a line width of 1 pixel)

Comment: This is definitely explained in any good Bresenham algo description.

Comment: Do you have a reference link I can read off of?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first octant, the only choices are right or up-right, and you take the closest to the exact line. The error is computed incrementally.

Comment: What if lines had slopes greater than 1? How would we accomplish drawing these lines?

Comment: @Kaylie Tess Algorithm in the first octant is simpler, You always can reflect points against x=y line

Comment: @KaylieTess: the processing must be specialized for the other octants, by swapping x/y or changing the signs. This is routine work.